# RecyclerView With ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, expandable

I am follow this tutorial :

[Android Studio Tutorial - Expandable RecyclerView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-BNn97nLKA)

it's succeed.

but I want to more colorful like this:

[image: Group with ImageView]

there are some beautiful images show in Group .

Please help me , Thanks.

my child class is Product.class

```
public class Product implements Parcelable{
   public final String name;
   public final int icon;

   public Product(String name, int icon) {
         this.name = name;
         this.icon = icon;
   }

   protected Product(Parcel in) {
         name = in.readString();
         icon = in.readInt();
   }

   public static final Creator<Product> CREATOR = new Creator<Product>() {

       public Product createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Product(in);
       }

       public Product[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Product[size];
       }
    };

    public int describeContents() {
          return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeInt(icon);
    }
  }
```

my Group is Company.class :

```
 public class Company extends ExpandableGroup<Product>{
   public Company(String title, List<Product> items) {
      super(title, items);
   }
 }
```

CompanyViewHolder.java:

```
 public class CompanyViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {
   TextView mTextView;
   ImageView arrow;
   private ImageView icon;

 public CompanyViewHolder(View itemView) {
   super(itemView);
   mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
   arrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arraw);
   icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.company_icon);
 }

 public void bind(Company company){
    mTextView.setText(company.getTitle());
    icon.setImageResource ...??
 }
```

Comment: you have to set custom ChildView & GroupView in BaseExpandableListAdapter

Comment: What is your question? how to make more beautiful images?

Comment: @AIMIN PAN  YES , I want to show images in Group.

Comment: you want to design like this link **[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF6VC.png)** @TzuyuLin

Comment: @Ali , YES , But in tutorial , there are not show any images in Group , although I know how to show images in Child , but in Group , I can't find any way?

Comment: @TzuyuLin https://www.dev2qa.com/android-expandablelistview-example/ check this example

Comment: refer this link : https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/ @TzuyuLin

Comment: add 3rd attribute to class for imageurl, add it to your data source and parse it the way you are parsing other two. You can use libraries like Glide or Picasso to load images from url.

Comment: @Karan Mer , I try to overwrite "ExpandableGroup<Product>" , but it's 3rd library , I can't overwrite.

Comment: @TzuyuLin so you are implementing same example as in video?

Comment: @Jins Lukose , yes. I also let images in chind item (Product) , but I still not know how to setup images in Group.

Comment: @TzuyuLin check the class GenreDataFactory.java in that example, there it say's clearly

Comment: @Jins Lukose , Thank you very much , I know what to do .

Comment: @TzuyuLin welcome i will make it as an answer mark it and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check GenreDataFactory.java in that example

```
public class GenreDataFactory {



public static List<Genre> makeGenres() {
    return Arrays.asList(makeRockGenre(),
        makeJazzGenre(),
        makeClassicGenre(),
        makeSalsaGenre(),
        makeBluegrassGenre());
  }

  public static List<MultiCheckGenre> makeMultiCheckGenres() {
    return Arrays.asList(makeMultiCheckRockGenre(),
        makeMultiCheckJazzGenre(),
        makeMultiCheckClassicGenre(),
        makeMultiCheckSalsaGenre(),
        makeMulitCheckBluegrassGenre());
  }

  public static List<SingleCheckGenre> makeSingleCheckGenres() {
    return Arrays.asList(makeSingleCheckRockGenre(),
        makeSingleCheckJazzGenre(),
        makeSingleCheckClassicGenre(),
        makeSingleCheckSalsaGenre(),
        makeSingleCheckBluegrassGenre());
  }

  public static Genre makeRockGenre() {
    return new Genre("Rock", makeRockArtists(), R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar);
  }

  public static MultiCheckGenre makeMultiCheckRockGenre() {
    return new MultiCheckGenre("Rock", makeRockArtists(), R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar);
  }

  public static SingleCheckGenre makeSingleCheckRockGenre() {
    return new SingleCheckGenre("Rock", makeRockArtists(), R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar);
  }

  public static List<Artist> makeRockArtists() {
    Artist queen = new Artist("Queen", true);
    Artist styx = new Artist("Styx", false);
    Artist reoSpeedwagon = new Artist("REO Speedwagon", false);
    Artist boston = new Artist("Boston", true);

    return Arrays.asList(queen, styx, reoSpeedwagon, boston);
  }

  public static Genre makeJazzGenre() {
    return new Genre("Jazz", makeJazzArtists(), R.drawable.ic_saxaphone);
  }

  public static MultiCheckGenre makeMultiCheckJazzGenre() {
    return new MultiCheckGenre("Jazz", makeJazzArtists(), R.drawable.ic_saxaphone);
  }

  public static SingleCheckGenre makeSingleCheckJazzGenre() {
    return new SingleCheckGenre("Jazz", makeJazzArtists(), R.drawable.ic_saxaphone);
  }

  public static List<Artist> makeJazzArtists() {
    Artist milesDavis = new Artist("Miles Davis", true);
    Artist ellaFitzgerald = new Artist("Ella Fitzgerald", true);
    Artist billieHoliday = new Artist("Billie Holiday", false);

    return Arrays.asList(milesDavis, ellaFitzgerald, billieHoliday);
  }

  public static Genre makeClassicGenre() {
    return new Genre("Classic", makeClassicArtists(), R.drawable.ic_violin);
  }

  public static MultiCheckGenre makeMultiCheckClassicGenre() {
    return new MultiCheckGenre("Classic", makeClassicArtists(), R.drawable.ic_violin);
  }

  public static SingleCheckGenre makeSingleCheckClassicGenre() {
    return new SingleCheckGenre("Classic", makeClassicArtists(), R.drawable.ic_violin);
  }

  public static List<Artist> makeClassicArtists() {
    Artist beethoven = new Artist("Ludwig van Beethoven", false);
    Artist bach = new Artist("Johann Sebastian Bach", true);
    Artist brahms = new Artist("Johannes Brahms", false);
    Artist puccini = new Artist("Giacomo Puccini", false);

    return Arrays.asList(beethoven, bach, brahms, puccini);
  }

  public static Genre makeSalsaGenre() {
    return new Genre("Salsa", makeSalsaArtists(), R.drawable.ic_maracas);
  }

  public static MultiCheckGenre makeMultiCheckSalsaGenre() {
    return new MultiCheckGenre("Salsa", makeSalsaArtists(), R.drawable.ic_maracas);
  }

  public static SingleCheckGenre makeSingleCheckSalsaGenre() {
    return new SingleCheckGenre("Salsa", makeSalsaArtists(), R.drawable.ic_maracas);
  }

  public static List<Artist> makeSalsaArtists() {
    Artist hectorLavoe = new Artist("Hector Lavoe", true);
    Artist celiaCruz = new Artist("Celia Cruz", false);
    Artist willieColon = new Artist("Willie Colon", false);
    Artist marcAnthony = new Artist("Marc Anthony", false);

    return Arrays.asList(hectorLavoe, celiaCruz, willieColon, marcAnthony);
  }

  public static Genre makeBluegrassGenre() {
    return new Genre("Bluegrass", makeBluegrassArtists(), R.drawable.ic_banjo);
  }

  public static MultiCheckGenre makeMulitCheckBluegrassGenre() {
    return new MultiCheckGenre("Bluegrass", makeBluegrassArtists(), R.drawable.ic_banjo);
  }

  public static SingleCheckGenre makeSingleCheckBluegrassGenre() {
    return new SingleCheckGenre("Bluegrass", makeBluegrassArtists(), R.drawable.ic_banjo);
  }

  public static List<Artist> makeBluegrassArtists() {
    Artist billMonroe = new Artist("Bill Monroe", false);
    Artist earlScruggs = new Artist("Earl Scruggs", false);
    Artist osborneBrothers = new Artist("Osborne Brothers", true);
    Artist johnHartford = new Artist("John Hartford", false);

    return Arrays.asList(billMonroe, earlScruggs, osborneBrothers, johnHartford);
  }

}
```

Comment: May I ask you another question ? If I want my child's layout is GridView layout , What do I do ? Thanks.

Comment: @TzuyuLin i think that is not possible in this example, because here LayoutManager is Linear